# IOS 8 Corporate app download HTML page does not close

Tags: html, ios8

I´ve made an HTML page for downloading a corporate iPhone application (via plist distribution).

```
 <div>
 <a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.example.com/example.plist"><img    style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block;margin-top:22%;margin-bottom:0%" src="download.png"/></a>
 </div>
```

Now on IOS7 when clicking the link the focus of page vanishes and the home screen is shown where you can follow the downloading progress.

On IOS8 when clicking the link the html page does not lose focus. The home screen is not shown and the user cannot follow the download progress.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's annoying, but, starting in iOS 8, opening an itms-services link will not send Safari to the background.

You'll have to add some text to your webpage that says something like "When you do tap the Download Button, please tap your Home button to view the progress of the App Installation." You might even want to get some Javascript going to react to the tap on the download button to bring some attention to that message.

This is a good thread that covers both the cases of itms-services links from within apps and from within Safari:
[ios 8 openUrl itms-services does not exit current app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913834/ios-8-openurl-itms-services-does-not-exit-current-app)