# itms-services protocol get click result, cancel or install?

Tags: ios8, uialertcontroller

In iOS8 when i use

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=...]]`

to install an enterprise app, the system will call out an alert asking you whether to install or not, now the question come, I need to know which button the user clicked, so I can refresh my app and some other actions, does anybody get the same problem?

Here are some similar question links below :

[ios 8 openUrl itms-services does not exit current app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913834/ios-8-openurl-itms-services-does-not-exit-current-app)

[Can I get message when I show UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607170/can-i-get-message-when-i-show-uialertview)

Comment: by the way , i find there is an app has resolve this problem, its name is haima apple assistant. so , absolutely there is a solution.

Comment: Fortunetly, i have got the method, we can use the private API `installProgressForBundleID:makeSynchronous:` in LSApplicationWorkspace.h.  to get the status of the installing app, although i still can not get the result of system alertview, it fit to me anyway. hope to be helpful for someone who faces the same problem.