# Over the air (OTA) installation for iOS8 app using itms-services URL

Tags: ios, ota

I am using a web to distribute the enterprise apps using itms-services URL.
Before iOS 8, when users browse the website through iOS devices and click the download button. The iOS device will quit the Safari and back to springboard.

However in iOS 8 it will stay into the web and without any feedback after click the download button.

Are there anyways to solve this issue? Thanks so much.

Comment: any solutions to this ?

Comment: seems Apple has changed the behaviour and there are no ways to solve this problem. I recommend to display message on the screen using javascript when users click the download button.

Comment: This thread is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913834/ios-8-openurl-itms-services-does-not-exit-current-app

Comment: Thanks I have also read this thread before